# Read JSON data to get key

Tags: json, regex, jq

Following is the sample output data in json format when i create a JIRA from command line using `curl` command.

```
   {"id":"123456","key":"ABCD-123","self":"http://abcd.com/rest/api/2/issue/123456"}
```

How can i read `ABCD-1234` into a variable. i have tried json data parser `jq` but it didn't help.

Reference Link: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/

Comment: Checkout https://jqplay.org/s/K7ShfPsh58

Comment: please try this `jq '.key'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `jq`:

```
key=$(jq -r '.key' file)
```

Comment: Thanks Cyrus. This works for me. I was making some error while reading using `jq`